# How to remove the header line in many files and renaming them using Perl

Tags: perl

I need help trying to process many small files. I need to remove the first line (header date line) if it exists and then rename the file `q_dat_20110816.out` => `q_dat_20110816.dat`.

I figured out how to open the file and do the match and print out the line I need to remove.

Now I need to figure out how to remove that line and then rename the file altogether.

How would you approach this?

Test code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = '/share/dev/dumps/q_dat_20110816.out';
$file = $ARGV[0] if (defined $ARGV[0]);

open DATA, "< $file" or die "Could not open '$file'\n";
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
        $count++;
        chomp($line);
        if ($line =~m/(Data for Process Q)/) {
                print "GOT THE DATE: --$line\n";
                exit;
        }
}
close DATA;
```

Sample file: q_dat_20110816.out

```
Data for Process Q, for 08/16/2011
Make    Model   Text
a       b       c
d       e       f
g       h       i
```

New file: q_dat_20110816.dat

```
Make    Model   Text
a       b       c
d       e       f
g       h       i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @old_file_names = @ARGV;

for my $f (@old_file_names){
    # Slurp up the lines.
    local @ARGV = ($f);
    my @lines = <>;

    # Drop the line you don't want.
    shift @lines if $lines[0] =~ /^Data for Process Q/;

    # Delete old file.
    unlink $f;

    # Write the new file.
    $f =~ s/\.out$/.dat/;
    open(my $h, '>', $f) or die "$f: $!";
    print $h @lines;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Low-on-memory father-son solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $fni (@ARGV) {
    open(FI, '<', $fni) or die "cant open in '$fni', $!,";
    my $fno = $fni; $fno =~ s/\.out$/.dat/;
    open(FO, '>', $fno) or die "cant open out '$fno', $!,";
    foreach ( <FI> ) {
        print FO unless $. == 1 and /^Data for Process Q/;
    };
    close FO;
    close FI;
    unlink $fni;
};
```

It is untested!